# How to plot geometry rings on map arcgis javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I am using the below code to plot the geometry on map but its show the simple line

```
var myPolygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));  
    myPolygon.addRing([[8359759.8001024649,3457372.361745805],[8360041.5200127913,3457368.3926527263],[8360323.0162886074,3457356.4885242302],[8360604.0654729316,3457336.6588100353],[8360884.444463687,3457308.9192513386],[8361163.9306908129,3457273.2918683169],[8361442.3022929383,3457229.8049426512],[8361719.3382935049,3457178.4929950722],[8361994.8187761763,3457119.3967579594],[8362268.5250594188,3457052.5631430051],[8362540.2398700882,3456978.0452039782],[8362809.7475159103,3456895.9020946049],[8363076.8340566978,3456806.1990216151],[8363341.2874741843,3456709.0071929777],[8363602.8978403229,3456604.4037613762],[8363861.4574839352,3456492.4717629612],[8364116.7611555625,3456373.3000514368],[8364368.6061903974,3456246.9832275268],[8364616.792669164,3456113.6215638765],[8364861.1235768143,3455973.3209254579],[8365101.4049589261,3455826.1926855291],[8365337.4460756639,3455672.3536372259],[8365569.0595531976,3455511.925900849],[8365796.061532435,3455345.0368269216],[8366018.2718149796,3455171.8188950978],[8366235.5140061732,3454992.409608996],[8366447.6156551195,3454806.9513870478],[8366654.4083915809,3454615.5914494419],[8366855.7280596355,3454418.481701259],[8367051.4148479803,3454215.7786118872],[8367241.3134168023,3454007.6430908116],[8367425.2730210815,3453794.2403598833],[8367603.1476302594,3453575.7398221637],[8367774.7960441597,3453352.3149274462],[8367940.0820050761,3453124.1430345722],[8368098.8743059365,3452891.405270637],[8368251.0468944563,3452654.2863872112],[8368396.4789732015,3452412.9746136782],[8368535.0550954817,3452167.6615078156],[8368666.6652569901,3451918.5418037339],[8368791.204983131,3451665.8132572914],[8368908.5754119512,3451409.6764891138],[8369018.6833726196,3451150.3348253355],[8369121.4414593866,3450887.9941361966],[8369216.7681009714,3450622.86267262],[8369304.5876253098,3450355.1509008976],[8369384.83031963,3450085.0713356165],[8369457.4324857863,3449812.8383709644],[8369522.3364908285,3449538.6681105359],[8369579.4908127487,3449262.7781957877],[8369628.8500813823,3448985.3876332697],[8369670.3751144232,3448706.7166207745],[8369704.0329485266,3448426.9863725398],[8369729.7968654772,3448146.418943644],[8369747.6464133989,3447865.2370537347],[8369757.567422987,3447583.6639102306],[8369759.5520187616,3447301.923031135],[8369753.5986253116,3447020.2380676023],[8369739.7119685523,3446738.8326264005],[8369717.9030719697,3446457.9300924074],[8369688.1892478727,3446177.7534512831],[8369650.5940836482,3445898.5251124618],[8369605.1474230373,3445620.4667325965],[8369551.8853424443,3445343.799039606],[8369490.8501223009,3445068.7416574545],[8369422.0902135009,3444795.5129318126],[8369345.66019894,3444524.3297567293],[8369261.620750187,3444255.4074024572],[8369170.0385793205,3443988.9593445673],[8369070.9863859722,3443725.197094488],[8368964.5427996181,3443464.3300316036],[8368850.7923171576,3443206.5652370444],[8368729.8252358409,3442952.1073293039],[8368601.7375815902,3442701.1583018051],[8368466.6310327696,3442453.9173625582],[8368324.6128394715,3442210.5807760232],[8368175.7957383832,3441971.3417073125],[8368020.2978632897,3441736.3900688523],[8367858.2426512977,3441505.912369627],[8367689.7587448517,3441280.0915671247],[8367514.9798896136,3441059.1069221026],[8367334.044828292,3440843.1338562854],[8367147.0971905068,3440632.3438131129],[8366954.2853787728,3440426.9041216462],[8366755.762450696,3440226.9778637365],[8366551.6859974721,3440032.7237445684],[8366342.2180187898,3439844.2959666788],[8366127.5247942274,3439661.8441075454],[8365907.7767512659,3439485.5130008501],[8365683.1483299909,3439315.4426215081],[8365453.8178446256,3439151.7679745522],[8365219.9673419781,3438994.6189879649],[8364981.7824569307,3438844.1204095362],[8364739.4522650801,3438700.3917078399],[8364493.1691326415,3438563.5469773947],[8364243.1285637524,3438433.6948480955],[8363989.5290452708,3438310.9383989796],[8363732.5718892142,3438195.3750764015],[8363472.4610729571,3438087.0966166779],[8363209.4030773081,3437986.1889732657],[8362943.6067225998,3437892.7322485312],[8362675.2830029288,3437806.800630162],[8362404.6449186569,3437728.4623322762],[8362131.9073073342,3437657.7795412731],[8361857.2866731538,3437594.8083664682],[8361581.0010150867,3437539.5987955523],[8361303.2696538325,3437492.1946549104],[8361024.313057716,3437452.6335748318],[8360744.3526676763,3437420.9469596385],[8360463.610721481,3437397.1599627552],[8360182.3100773152,3437381.2914667432],[8359900.6740368651,3437373.35406831],[8359618.9261680646,3437373.35406831],[8359337.2901276145,3437381.2914667432],[8359055.9894834487,3437397.1599627552],[8358775.2475372534,3437420.9469596385],[8358495.2871472137,3437452.6335748318],[8358216.3305510972,3437492.1946549104],[8357938.5991898431,3437539.5987955523],[8357662.313531776,3437594.8083664682],[8357387.6928975955,3437657.7795412731],[8357114.9552862728,3437728.4623322762],[8356844.3172020009,3437806.800630162],[8356575.9934823299,3437892.7322485312],[8356310.1971276216,3437986.1889732657],[8356047.1391319726,3438087.0966166779],[8355787.0283157155,3438195.3750764015],[8355530.071159659,3438310.9383989796],[8355276.4716411773,3438433.6948480955],[8355026.4310722882,3438563.5469773947],[8354780.1479398496,3438700.3917078399],[8354537.817747999,3438844.1204095362],[8354299.6328629516,3438994.6189879649],[8354065.7823603041,3439151.7679745522],[8353836.4518749388,3439315.4426215081],[8353611.8234536638,3439485.5130008501],[8353392.0754107023,3439661.8441075454],[8353177.3821861399,3439844.2959666788],[8352967.9142074576,3440032.7237445684],[8352763.8377542337,3440226.9778637365],[8352565.3148261569,3440426.9041216462],[8352372.503014423,3440632.3438131129],[8352185.5553766377,3440843.1338562849],[8352004.6203153161,3441059.1069221026],[8351829.841460078,3441280.0915671247],[8351661.357553632,3441505.912369627],[8351499.30234164,3441736.3900688523],[8351343.8044665465,3441971.3417073125],[8351194.9873654582,3442210.5807760232],[8351052.9691721601,3442453.9173625582],[8350917.8626233395,3442701.1583018051],[8350789.7749690888,3442952.1073293039],[8350668.8078877721,3443206.5652370444],[8350555.0574053116,3443464.3300316036],[8350448.6138189575,3443725.197094488],[8350349.5616256092,3443988.9593445673],[8350257.9794547427,3444255.4074024572],[8350173.9400059897,3444524.3297567293],[8350097.5099914288,3444795.5129318126],[8350028.7500826288,3445068.7416574545],[8349967.7148624854,3445343.799039606],[8349914.4527818924,3445620.4667325965],[8349869.0061212815,3445898.5251124618],[8349831.410957057,3446177.7534512831],[8349801.69713296,3446457.9300924069],[8349779.8882363774,3446738.8326264005],[8349766.0015796181,3447020.2380676023],[8349760.0481861681,3447301.923031135],[8349762.0327819427,3447583.6639102306],[8349771.9537915308,3447865.2370537347],[8349789.8033394525,3448146.418943644],[8349815.5672564032,3448426.9863725398],[8349849.2250905065,3448706.7166207749],[8349890.7501235474,3448985.3876332697],[8349940.109392181,3449262.7781957877],[8349997.2637141012,3449538.6681105359],[8350062.1677191434,3449812.8383709644],[8350134.7698852997,3450085.0713356165],[8350215.0125796199,3450355.1509008976],[8350302.8321039584,3450622.86267262],[8350398.1587455431,3450887.9941361966],[8350500.9168323101,3451150.3348253355],[8350611.0247929785,3451409.6764891138],[8350728.3952217987,3451665.8132572914],[8350852.9349479396,3451918.5418037339],[8350984.545109448,3452167.6615078156],[8351123.1212317282,3452412.9746136782],[8351268.5533104734,3452654.2863872112],[8351420.7258989932,3452891.405270637],[8351579.5181998536,3453124.1430345722],[8351744.80416077,3453352.3149274462],[8351916.4525746703,3453575.7398221637],[8352094.3271838482,3453794.2403598833],[8352278.2867881274,3454007.6430908116],[8352468.1853569495,3454215.7786118872],[8352663.8721452942,3454418.481701259],[8352865.1918133488,3454615.5914494419],[8353071.9845498102,3454806.9513870478],[8353284.0861987565,3454992.409608996],[8353501.3283899501,3455171.8188950978],[8353723.5386724947,3455345.0368269216],[8353950.5406517321,3455511.925900849],[8354182.1541292658,3455672.3536372259],[8354418.1952460036,3455826.1926855291],[8354658.4766281154,3455973.3209254579],[8354902.8075357657,3456113.6215638765],[8355150.9940145323,3456246.9832275268],[8355402.8390493672,3456373.3000514368],[8355658.1427209945,3456492.4717629612],[8355916.7023646068,3456604.4037613762],[8356178.3127307454,3456709.0071929777],[8356442.7661482319,3456806.1990216151],[8356709.8526890194,3456895.9020946049],[8356979.3603348415,3456978.0452039782],[8357251.075145511,3457052.5631430051],[8357524.7814287534,3457119.3967579594],[8357800.2619114248,3457178.4929950722],[8358077.2979119914,3457229.8049426512],[8358355.6695141168,3457273.2918683169],[8358635.1557412427,3457308.9192513386],[8358915.5347319981,3457336.6588100353],[8359196.5839163223,3457356.4885242302],[8359478.0801921384,3457368.3926527263],[8359759.8001024649,3457372.361745805]]);  

    // map is in web mercator so transform the geometry  
    var poly_wm = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(myPolygon);  

    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID);  
    polygonGraphic = new esri.Graphic(poly_wm, symbol); ///*** how to convert the polygon geometry????? *******////  
    map.graphics.add(polygonGraphic); 

    var pt = new Point(8359759.8001024649,3457372.361745805, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
    map.centerAndZoom(pt,15);
```

and the line shown zoom out from the map. Basically this geometry rings i am getting from the buffer circle and am trying to plot on the map in circle form

Comment: I think you are confuse with the spatial reference, wkid 4326 is geographic coordinates, but the coordinates that you are using are not geographic. If your coordinates are Web Mercator, then it is wkid 3857.

Comment: How can i give the radius in this geometry to draw the circle?